# How to convert dictionary terms to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I used `xmltodict` to extract data from an XML file to dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict as xd
parsed = xd.parse(data.strip())
df = pd.DataFrame(parsed["SAMPLE_SET"]["SAMPLE"])
```

I got the XML converted to dataframe, but one of the column contains data as follows: `df['SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES']`

```
OrderedDict([('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE', [OrderedDict([('TAG', 'gender'), ('VALUE', 'male')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'phenotype'), ('VALUE', 'CML, fuo9')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'sample type'), ('VALUE', 'normal tissue')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'subject_id'), ('VALUE', '1')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'ENA-CHECKLIST'), ('VALUE', 'ERCXX1')])])])
OrderedDict([('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE', [OrderedDict([('TAG', 'gender'), ('VALUE', 'female')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'phenotype'), ('VALUE', 'CML, fuo4')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'sample type'), ('VALUE', 'blood')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'subject_id'), ('VALUE', '1')]), OrderedDict([('TAG', 'ENA-CHECKLIST'), ('VALUE', 'ERCXX2')])])])
```

I want to split these terms and add to new column in the dataframe as:

```
gender  phenotype   sample type     subject_id  ENA-CHECKLIST
male    CML, fuo9   normal tissue       1       ERCXX1
female  CML, fuo4   normal tissue       1       ERCXX1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom function to extract the dictionaries then [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to the existing one:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame({'SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES': [
    OrderedDict([('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE', [OrderedDict([('TAG', 'gender'), ('VALUE', 'male')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'phenotype'), ('VALUE', 'CML, fuo9')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'sample type'), ('VALUE', 'normal tissue')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'subject_id'), ('VALUE', '1')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'ENA-CHECKLIST'), ('VALUE', 'ERCXX1')])])]),
    OrderedDict([('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE', [OrderedDict([('TAG', 'gender'), ('VALUE', 'female')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'phenotype'), ('VALUE', 'CML, fuo4')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'sample type'), ('VALUE', 'blood')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'subject_id'), ('VALUE', '1')]),
                                       OrderedDict([('TAG', 'ENA-CHECKLIST'), ('VALUE', 'ERCXX2')])])])
]})


def extract(di):
    return {m['TAG']: m['VALUE'] for m in di['SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE']}


extracted = pd.DataFrame([extract(d) for d in df['SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES'].tolist()])

res = pd.concat((df.drop('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES', 1), extracted), axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   gender  phenotype    sample type subject_id ENA-CHECKLIST
0    male  CML, fuo9  normal tissue          1        ERCXX1
1  female  CML, fuo4          blood          1        ERCXX2
```

Comment: the content of the dataframe is changed in your code. 
`{'SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE': [{'TAG': 'gender', 'VALUE...`


but mine is:
`OrderedDict([('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE', [OrderedDict([('TAG', 'gender'), ('VALUE',`

Comment: @user288925 Could you be more specific, I don't understand what you mean. Which dataframe are you referring to?

Comment: When is that changed? Do you want the function to return an OrderedDict?

Comment: The content of the dataframe has changed in your code and is working on the data you presented. When I run same on my data `df['SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES']` it fails

Comment: It fails how, what is the error? Also an OrderedDict is a dictionary....

Comment: the error is `string indices must be integers`

Comment: `OrderedDict` is not a function here. Its the data in the `df['SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226087/discussion-between-dani-mesejo-and-user288925).